# как в datetime получить месяц не числом?

Tags: python, datetime

мне нужно из модуля datetime получить месяц не числом, а строчкой  русскими символами

например, заместо 3.10.2021 нужно получить 3 ноября 2021 года

Comment: можете в вопрос добавить пример, что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать функцию по преобразованию:

```
date = '3.10.2021'

def transform_date(date):

    months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня',
           'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря']
    day,month,year = date.split('.')
    return f'{day} {months[int(month) - 1]} {year} года'

print(transform_date(date))
```

Comment: Только более красиво было бы сразу распаковать сплит на 3 переменных - день, месяц, и год. Индексированные сущности не так красивы.

Comment: @CrazyElf укоротил)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать преобразованием объекта datetime, если вам не важны окончания по склонениям:

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru')
mydate='3.10.2021'

month = datetime.strptime(mydate, "%d.%m.%Y").strftime("%B")
print(month)
```

> Октябрь